Work in an electrochemical system
Good day guys,
I was looking at Bard's book on Electrochemical Methods, in Chapter two the change in Gibbs energy for a reaction is given by:
$$\Delta G = -nFE_{rxn}$$
This explanation is consistent with the one given in Thermal Physics by Schroeder:
$$\Delta G = W^{rev}_{electric}$$
Bard's book writes the nernst equation as:
$$E_{rxn} = E^0_{rxn}+\frac{RT}{nF}ln\frac{C_O}{C_R}$$
However, I have seen derivations of the Nernst Equation that use the definition of electrochemical potential:
$$\mu' = \mu^0 +RTln(a_i) + z_iF\phi$$
They take the condition of electrochemical equilibrium:
$$\Delta G = \sum_{Prod} s_i\mu'-\sum_{React} s_i\mu' = 0$$
They solve for the potential difference between phases to arrive to this form of the Nernst equation:
$$\Delta \phi = \Delta \phi^0+\frac{RT}{nF}ln\frac{a_O}{a_R} $$
To me it is not clear why one approach considers $\Delta G = 0$ while the other one does not and both are supposed to describe the system's equilibrium potential.
I also wonder, how the term($-nFE_{rxn}$) amounts for  both the chemical work ($s_i \mu_i$) and electric work ($z_iF\phi$).

I think you will get better answers here https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Cross-posted at Chemistry: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/185294/36303
